# Why can't Azure Storage Explorer connect to storage accounts created by Azure Media Services?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-media-services, azure-storage

I'm using Azure Storage Explorer to connect to storage accounts that I've created by hand on Azure. However when I go to browse the storage account that was created by Azure when I created a Media Services account, I'm unable to connect to it.

I'm using blob.core.windows.net as the storage endpoint domain, and setting the storage account name and storage account key to be the same as Azure has defined it in the dashboard, but attempts to connect (with or without HTTPS) result in a 502-Bad Gateway HTTP error.

I'd like an easy way to browse all media files I've created without having to write special code. Has anyone been able to get this to work?

Comment: Are you browsing directly to the Azure Container or attempting to access it programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All storage accounts regardless the way they are being created are browsable with Storage Explorer!

For such storage accounts, created when you Create Media Services, you have to use the `Storage Account Name` and `Storage Account Key`, but not the `Media Service Account Name` and `Media Service Account Key`! You will not be able to access `Storage service` with `Media Key` and vice-versa.

Comment: Where do you find these values? I'm confused.

Comment: And what do you put for the "Storage endpoints domain" field? Leave it as default?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a Media Services account, one/multiple storage accounts could be attached to a particular media services account. Let's say your account name is "MediaStorage123". I believe you need to pass the following data to storage explorer:

- Account name/key: this can be found in the bottom of your storage account page in Azure portal: press Manage Key button you will see the data.
- storage endpoint domain: Not sure why you need this, but if so, you can see the information in Dashboard of your media services account: https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, In my case (with the use of proxy) I had do install a previous version of the Azure Storage Explorer